# Drupal 7 - Image Field Upload/Deletion not working

Tags: ajax, image, drupal, upload

I use Drupal 7.33 and Image Field. I can't upload or delete images when JS is turned on in my browser. So it can't be a file-permission or php problem.

From my nginx-log-file:

```
[warn] 812#0: *7074 a client request body is buffered to a temporary
file /var/lib/nginx/body/0000000023, client: 174.61.242.24,
server: www.example.com, request: "POST /file/ajax/field_foto/und/0/form
Bw9u5Xhbowcr3qGBI4mPYtnNtC0AUHpyi2L_xesa9qY HTTP/1.1", host: "www.example.com",
referrer: "http://www.example.com/node/8/edit"
```

I also use the jQuery-Update Module with Version 1.5 for administrative sites.

Console-Error:

```
'Attr.nodeValue' is deprecated. Please use 'value' instead.
jquery-1.5.2.min.js:16
Refused to display 'http://www.example.com/file/ajax/field_foto/und/0/form-wNmrRuGxQgvWtN_glNEmnFI34Bm-m_sMC-iuGVn0Wmk'
 in a frame because it set 'X-Frame-Options' to 'DENY'. about:blank:1

Uncaught SecurityError: Sandbox access violation: Blocked a frame at
"http://www.example.com" from accessing a frame at "null".
The frame being accessed is sandboxed and lacks the "allow-same-origin" flag.
js_4QRrlXrX4C71F2nR2dAhf6BenDZnNcl6GHuDAJyosZw.js:101t
js_4QRrlXrX4C71F2nR2dAhf6BenDZnNcl6GHuDAJyosZw.js:101
```

With the default jQuery Version provided by the theme, I get this error (pop-up), when I try to delete the file:

```
An AJAX HTTP request terminated abnormally.
Debugging information follows.
Path: /file/ajax/field_foto/und/0/form-3_O5Rsz9PLD9NJCuwI157oZdHW1XJ8gOdTtJYQTT1oI
StatusText: n/a
ResponseText: 
ReadyState: undefined
```

I've tested this with Chrome, Firefox and Safari.

The Status-Report from Drupal is OK.

Thanks for your help ;)

Comment: Are there any js errors reported in the developer console of your browser?

Comment: Yes, thanks - I added it to the question.

Comment: AFAIK, the image field does not use any iframes. What other fields do you have on the node?

Comment: No more fields, just image and body.

Comment: Do you have 'overlay' on? maybe that is the problem. Why are you using jquery update on the admin theme? I would suggest you use the standard jquery that comes with drupal for the admin theme. The latest dev version on jquery update has an option for this.

Comment: I turned off 'overlay', updated the jquery-update module, set it to use the default version provied by the theme, cleared cache and runned cron. Now I'm getting another error (see main post).

Comment: I have read that this may be caused by a Chrome extension. Are you using Chrome? If so try another browser or disable Chrome extensions.

Comment: It may also have to do with your tmp directory maybe. Is you tmp directory set up correctly? Check for problems on your status report page "admin/reports/status".

Comment: I used Firefox, Chrome and Safari, but it was not successfull. Status-Report = green: File system - Writable (public download method). Very strange...

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This small configuration should fix the issue:

**Configuring Apache**

To configure Apache to send the X-Frame-Options header for all pages, add this to your site's configuration:

```
Header always append X-Frame-Options SAMEORIGIN
```

**Configuring nginx**

To configure nginx to send the X-Frame-Options header, add this either to your http, server or location configuration:

```
add_header X-Frame-Options SAMEORIGIN;
```

Answer (score 0):

This only seems to be happening to me on localhost. Overlay is off and the only error I see in Chrome dev tools console is "'Attr.nodeValue' is deprecated. Please use 'value' instead.".